# How to manage JWT when Cookies are disabled

Tags: javascript, java, json, rest, cookies

I've been reading articles about JSON Web Token (which is completely new to me) and its safe mechanism to transmit information between parties in order to avoid server Sessions.

I'm building a web app from scratch using Java, Tomcat, Jersey framework for Web Services and JOSE4J for the JWT.

Many articles advice to use Cookies httpOnly instead of localStorage

I've already created a restful method like this with a cookie and the jwt

```
@GET
@Path("/authenticate")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response authenticate(
        @HeaderParam("username") String username,
        @HeaderParam("password") String password) throws JSONException,
        IOException, JoseException {
        Service service = Service.getInstance();
        EmployeeProfile employeeProfile = service.authenticate(username, password);
        // Temporarily httponly and secure as false to test
        NewCookie cookie = new NewCookie("jwt", service.getToken(), null, null, null, 900, false, false);
        return Response.status(200).cookie(cookie).entity(employeeProfile).build();
    }
    return Response.status(204).entity(null).build();
}
```

When I run my webapp in Chrome I can see that the cookie was saved correctly.

Now I can use this token to call further restful methods with no need to authenticate again, but what if Cookies are disabled? I cannot retrieve the cookie as I tested in incognito mode. In that case I can verify if cookies are enabled and warn the user to enable them in order to proceed with the login process.

To check cookies I do this:

```
$.cookie('test_cookie', 'cookie_value', { path: '/' });
if ($.cookie('test_cookie') !== 'cookie_value') {
    //Cookies are disabled. Show a modal.
}
```

But this is very restrictive. So I wonder what would be my alternative to retrieve the jwt from server? I am not very sure about this, but should I change the controller to send the jwt as a part of the response in json and keep it in the localStorage even if this can expose my token to XSS attacks? However, using cookies can be also susceptible to CRSF attacks but not if I set httpOnly and secure properties to true, but in that case I won't be able to read the cookie with javascript. I am confused about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use localStorage. If you're worried about XSS attacks then use iframes for JavaScript code you do not trust.

Answer (score 0):

You are right , You need to change your controller and send the JWT is part of the response as well as the cookies with flag httpOnly due securities, but the question is are decrypting JWT in client side and using some value from there. if "No", then no need to send JWT as part of the response.. if "Yes", better take out all that values from the token and send a separate json object in response header.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is still a little bit confusing because this is new to me. You mean to send the JWT though Response in the header as httpOnly? I will do the validation of the JWT in server side. I just  want to receive the JWT from authentication and keep it for the next calls. I don't exactly where to hold the JWT. Can you provide a simple example to understand better your answer or a good link to read? I'm reading a blog about JWT and Authorization header. But I don't know if it is that you meant. Thank you again and regards.